# Source Qualifier SQL Query in Informatica Powercenter

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to perform a simple transformation in Informatica Powercenter using a Filter and overriding the SQL query of the source qualifier. However, even though without overriding the sql query the transformation works perfectly and retrieves all the records that I need from source to target, when I override the query (by simply adding a where clause to the default query) 0 rows are being processed. My map looks like this:

[image]

Any idea why overriding the default query doesn't fetch any records?

Comment: This seems strange. Do you get data when you issue the SQL in database with the `where` clause? Just get the query from Informatica session log and run it in database and check if it returns any data. Infa simply adds the where clause the the SELECT . So it should return data.

Comment: Yes, I get data from the database if I run the exact query. Also, if I do not override the SQL Query and simply add the where condition in the Source Qualifier properties, it works.

Comment: see, if you have a SQL override and then add a where condition then SQL override will be executed and where clause will be ignored. If you remove overwrite sql and add only where clause then it should work. Please check few things 1. check if you have session level SQL override. 2. check if the database schema is correctly mentioned in session and SQ override. 3. The database you are checking and informatica session are same.